# Iterate over LinkedHashMap in reverse

Tags: java, iteration, linkedhashmap

I have a `LinkedHashMap` (because the order of entry is important).
I want to be able to iterate over it's entries (key, value pairs) like an array 
from **end to start** so the foreach [methods](http://java67.blogspot.co.il/2014/05/3-examples-to-loop-map-in-java-foreach.html) doesn't fit here
something like :

```
for (int i = DestIndexStartPair.entrySet().size() , i> 0 ; i--) {
    entry = DestIndexStartPair.entrySet()[i];
    String Endsection = output.substring(entry.value());
    System.out.println(Endsection );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working solution**:

```
List<Entry<Foo,Bar>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<Foo,Bar>>(map.entries());

for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Entry<Foo,Bar> entry = list.get(i);
}
```

Obviously, the trade off here is that you have to **copy the whole map** into the array list. If your map is too big (whatever is too big), you might have performance and memory problems.

Comment: Didn't he say this *doesn't* work ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see right. Corrected.

Comment: this one works great !

Answer (score 4):

There is no efficient way to iterate over a `Set` (such as `entrySet`) in reverse order. If you need iteration in both directions, then for the opposite direction the best approach is to copy into a temporary list and iterate the list in reverse.

Of course, if you only need one direction, then you should just ensure the `LinkedHashMap` has *that* order instead of the opposite.

Comment: Maintaining the ordering correctly seems like the most practical solution...

Answer (score 2):

Looking at map implementation might help more. May be by overriding in more appropriate way this can be achieved in balanced way as in performance or thread safety etc. But here is small hack that may help,

```
public class HackedLinkedHashMap<K,V> extends LinkedHashMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V> {

private LinkedList<K> keyList = new LinkedList<>();

@Override
public V put(K key, V value){
    V obj = super.put(key, value);
    keyList.addFirst(key);

    return obj;
}

public LinkedList<K> getReversedKeyList(){
    return keyList;
}}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Test conference");
    HackedLinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HackedLinkedHashMap();
    for(Integer i=0;i<100;i++){
        map.put(i, i);
    }   
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = map.getReversedKeyList().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best method to it , I'll try it as well

Answer (score 0):

An EntrySet is a Set and thus doesn't normally have an index.

So, what you need would be...

```
for(Entry<K,V> entry : DestIndexStartPair.entrySet()) {
    String Endsection = output.substring(entry.value()); // whatever output is
    System.out.println(Endsection );
}
```

...and then store the result, and reverse it.

Comment: hi , I need end to start not start to end

Comment: Don't see much choice except iterating over it and store it in a list and then doing it backwards again.